# SendGrid ActionMailer to work in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendmail, actionmailer, sendgrid

I want to integrate SendGrid in my app and test how things work locally so I have my code send an email on a new user registration. I have my controller calling Notifier.welcome_email(user).deliver

When I tail the logs, the only related thing I see is:

Rendered notifier/welcome_email.html.erb (1.3ms)

But no email gets sent. In my environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
:port           => '587',
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name      => '<user-name-is-here-actually.',
:password       => '<and-the-password>',
:domain         => 'domain.com',
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I still see nothing come through. Can anyone help me get this working locally?

Comment: I don't see any issues with your config. Do you have anything in your [email activity](http://sendgrid.com/logs/index)? Have you verified that your local environment can reach `smtp.sendgrid.net` via port `587`, with e.g. `telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately there's nothing in the email activity, development log (locally) and I can telnet to that address just fine. Is there anyway I can add some sort of logging to check that it's actually using those configs or if it's trying to send through sendgrid at all? How does it connect to the free instance I setup for on sendgrid though if the usernames on heroku and the one I signed up for on sendgrid don't match up? Does it pair on my heroku email address - do I have to connect them?

Comment: Alright I checked the credentials that I'm using through heroku and my personal and neither have activity. I need to complete the setup through the heroku account though so I'll try that first and retest.

Comment: Just tried after completing the setup for on my heroku created account and the email logs are still empty :/

Comment: Hi there, you can use either the free account or the account that heroku generates for you. [Instructions here](https://sendgrid.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181998-Heroku-Users-Find-your-Sendgrid-Credentials). If you are certain that your Heroku config is correct, you could try something like mailtrap.io and see if your messages make it there.

Comment: Just tried with mailcatcher and still nothing...hmm. What would I see in the logs on a successful sendgrid run besides the view being rendered?

Comment: Figured it out, it was because there wasn't the '.deliver' method after the Notifier command in the user registration. Now however, I get this message: Net::SMTPFatalError: 550 Cannot receive from specified address: Unauthenticated senders not allowed

Answer (score 1):

The solution was just to make sure to call 'deliver' on the Notifier method.